# Do BGEZAL and BTLZAL modify $31 if branch not taken?

Tags: mips, instruction-set

According to [this](http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/devel/assembly/mips-iv.pdf) specification of MIPS `BGEZAL` does the following operation:

```
I: tgt_offset ← sign_extend(offset || 02)
condition ← GPR[rs] ≥ 0GPRLEN
GPR[31] ← PC + 8
I+1: if condition then
PC ← PC + tgt_offset
endif
```

From what I understand from this, the linking `GPR[31] ← PC + 8` occurs even if the branch is not taken. Is this so or did I misunderstood it?

And if this is so what is the point of linking id the branch is not taken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out the question by myself, hope it can be useful for someone else:

The `link register $31` is **always** modified even if the branch is not taken, and this is because of hardware implementation. It is hard to implement hardware which doesn't alter the register. However it being always altered can be dealt with easily with software, by just saving the previous value of `$31` if it is needed regardless of the branch being changed or not..